# With PyCharm, how do I reference django files when using remote AWS interpreter?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have an existing django project on an AWS instance.  I have copied my Python files to my local machine.  PyCharm is configured to use the Python interpreter on the remote machine.  The django file references are, naturally, not resolved by PyCharm, since the django files are not on the local machine.

Is the usual procedure to copy all the django files from the remote server to my local machine.  Or is there another way to get PyCharm to know where to look to resolve the django references?

Answer (score 0):

(Using PyCharm 4.0) Go to `Tools` --> `Deployment` --> and either select an existing server connection or create a new one.  Under the `Mappings` tab, you can associate a local path with a remote path.  I keep my Django project folder mapped to the one on the server.

Once you hit OK, go back to `Tools` --> `Deployment`, and you should see a bunch of options available to you that were greyed out before, such as:

- `Upload to [server name]`
- `Download from [server name]`
- `Sync to Deployed to [server name]`
- `Automatic Upload`

I find Automatic Upload handy for when I want the changes in newly saved Django files reflected on the server within seconds of hitting save.